# 2 Namespaces causing 2 different errors

Tags: development, web-part, error

I am in the process of creating a method that will generate a list of web parts on a specific page. I have found that using the `SPLimitedWebPartManager` class will help me with the task. When I use the class i receive an error saying `The type or namespace name 'SPLimitedWebPartManager' does not exist`. So, I add the Namespace for the class `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages`. Doing this causing an ambiguous error on my main class `public partial class VisualWebPart1 : WebPart`. The `WebPart` is the bit that receives the error. When i comment out the Namespace `System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts` the ambiguous error goes away. Now, when i reload my page i get an error saying `<style xmlns=''> was not expected.`.

Now, my question(s).

Why can't I use both namespaces? I realize i can't because of the ambiguous error. but must be a good explanation

Why am I receiving this `<style xmlns=''> was not expected.` error? Steps to remove it?

Is there one namespace that will take care of both classes and not give me the `<style xmlns=''> was not expected.` error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both namespaces, you just have to set up a way of disambiguating which `WebPart` class you are referring to when you refer to it.

One way of doing that would be to include the entire namespace when you refer to the `WebPart` class, i.e.:

```
public partial class VisualWebPart1 : System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPart
```

Another option, and the first thing that came to my head when I read your question, is to set up namespace aliases:

```
using SysUI = System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
//
//
public partial class VisualWebPart1 : SysUI.WebPart
```

The main idea is that you just have to be specific and set up disambiguation.

Here's some [info on namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx) on MSDN.

As far as the other error, I don't know what's going on there.

Comment: Should have thought of giving them an alias earlier. I will have to research that error I received, it seems to be something with XML.